To make 'trim' and 'atrim' work synchronously
The following command trims a video using the trim video filter:
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "trim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:10',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" output.mp4

But if the video also contains audio stream, it will not be trimmed.
I tried
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "trim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:10',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -af "atrim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:10'" output.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter "trim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:10',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" output.mp4

but the 2nd version returns an error, and the 1st creates a "wrong" video. By "wrong" I mean that the output video is now somewhat consists of two parts, the 1st part is silent, and the 2nd does have a static image.
How to combine -vf trim and -af atrim so that they will work synchronously?
